# Script not running at powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this snippet of code

```
$actDate=Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
Start-job -name "FMLE" -command { cmd.exe /c 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2\FMLEcmd.exe' /p C:\tasks\testing_2\testing 2_$actDate.xml /ap username:password /ab username:password /l C:\Users\acruz\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.log }
```

I know for sure, that the var $actDate is not being replaced at the line, how shuld I do that?

My two questions are: how to replace the $actDate for its value and how to save the result of the job to one log

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

This does not works either:

```
$actDate = (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')
$Args = ("/p C:\tasks\testing_2\testing 2_$actDate.xml","/ap username:password", "/ab uysername:password", "/l C:\Users\acruz\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.log")
$Args

$j = Start-job -name "FMLE" -ScriptBlock { & 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2\FMLEcmd.exe' @args } -ArgumentList $args

Get-Job $j.Id
Receive-Job -Job $j | Out-File 'C:\Users\acruz\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.log' -encoding ASCII -append -force
```

Although $Args has the right information...

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work"?

Comment: It does not do nothing at all. 
If I run that command from bash it runs ok. But If I run it within that, it tells "Bad usage", and that is because the script is not replace $actDate for 2013-09-09... Still, I found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by doing it like this:

```
Start-job -Verbose -ScriptBlock {
    $actDate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
    cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2\"
    .\FMLEcmd.exe /p "C:\site.com.mx\tasks\test_23445678\test 23445678_$actDate.xml" /ap user:password /ab user:password /l C:\site.com.mx\task.log
}
```

By doing it with `-command` it does not work, cause it does not replace the variable at all. Also, if I do it with `-ArgumentList` either was replacing the variable `$actDate`, so I though that may be by adding the whole script within the block it was work... and indeed, it did it...

So I don't know why it does not works, but this is a fix for me.

Comment: The powershell attribute $actDate was out of context from the scriptblock `-command { }` the solution you said that works puts the variable in context...At least so i think :)

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you need to include the path using double quotes. A suggestion if you can then remove the space in the testing 2

`"C:\tasks\testing_2\testing2_$actDate.xml"`

To log result of the job use `Receive-Job` cmdlet.

**One more try:**
Try to put all paths in double quotes and then surround everything with a single quote after the cmd.exe /c part as shown below.  Try to achieve something simpler with a simple task and then try to add complexity

```
$job = Start-Job -name "Hel" -Command { cmd.exe /c '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" /?'}
```

Comment: I tried that, if I make -command { cmd.exe /c "c:\$actDate" } the ouptut in the console after Get-Job is cmd.exe /c "C:\$actDa.. instead of C:\2013-09-09...